# Problem loading raster QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, raster

I am very new at GIS. I am trying to load a raster so that I can complete a tutorial on georeferencing. The raster file is a jpeg. However, whenever I try to load the raster, it gives me solid colored lines that are completely distorted from the original. I realize this is probably a very simple fix. Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Can you provide QGIS version you are using and OS?

Comment: And please, which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the raster file look like outside of QGIS, I'm assuming the file is not corrupt? You might also want to try saving the JPEG as a TIFF and using the TIFF in QGIS.

Comment: This seems to have solved the problem. Once I changed the file to .tiff, I am able to open it un-corrupted. The version is 2.0.1.